# Moving /boot to new partition produces: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm attempting to move my `/boot` folder from the `/` partition, to `/dev/sdb`. The following script:

```
parted -s /dev/sdb mklabel msdos mkpart primary ext2 1M 100% set 1 boot on
mkfs.ext2 /dev/sdb1
mkdir /mnt/boot
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/boot
cd /boot
find . -depth -print0 | \
    cpio --null --sparse --make-directories --pass-through --verbose /mnt/boot
cd /
umount /mnt/boot
mv /boot /boot.orig
mkdir /boot
echo "/dev/sdb1 /boot ext2 ro 0 2" >>/etc/fstab
mount /dev/sdb1 /boot
parted /dev/sda set 1 boot off
grub-install /dev/sdb
update-grub
reboot
```

produces this error:

```
error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
grub rescue>
```

Any ideas?

**Edit**: It appears that the above script works fine, if the original `/boot` directory is on a separate partition (say `/dev/sda2`). It only fails if it's on the same partition as the `/` partition (`/dev/sda1`).

I've tried many, many variations of the above script, on both Ubuntu 13.04 and Fedora 19, and have yet to avoid the `file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found` error.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that grub is looking for `/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod` *on the new partition*.  As the root of that partition is now mounted at `/boot`, the file is currently located at `/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod` on the new partition.  You either need to reinstall `grub` to that partition or, as a temporary measure, you can create a symlink by calling `ln -s . /boot/boot`, which will allow the file to be found under either name.

Answer (score 3):

Do an "ls" to find your boot partition (new one that is) say (hdX,Y).

Then ls (hdX,Y)/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc

Do you see the file there?

Likely you need to boot with a rescue cd or usb, and reinstall grub. Something is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the `prefix` variable, which is hardcoded in the `core.img` image by `grub-install` doesn't match your partition layout anymore. You can temporarily override this variable manually and load GRUB once by running the following commands in the rescue shell :

```
set prefix=(hd0,1)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

The prefix should be the path to where GRUB's files (grub.cfg, etc) reside, it's usually something like `(hdX,Y)/boot/grub` in case of a single root partition, or `(hdX,Y)/grub` if you have a dedicated `/boot` partition. In case of mdadm-managed RAID, the `hdX,Y` would probably be `md/xxx` or `mduuid/xxxx...`.

If everything goes right, GRUB should be able to load its modules and load its `grub.cfg` and you should be able to start your OS. Once booted, run `grub-install` to regenerate a `core.img` (which will be embedded in the MBR of the disk) with the new prefix.

More info in their (awful) [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/GRUB-only-offers-a-rescue-shell.html).