# error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found

Tags: arch-linux, grub

I've tried to install Arch-Linux on a computer a *lot* of times on an External Drive **sdb**. No matter what I do, the same error keeps re-appearing, and never booting. `sdb2` is where arch-linux is installed, Filesystem is `ext4`.

I've looked at a ton of other posts ([here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70538/grub-error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found/265897), [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83268/moving-boot-to-new-partition-produces-file-boot-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not), and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266429/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found)) and it seems that none of them have helped me so far.

I've searched the `/boot` directory using **Grub-Rescue**, and it seems that **Grub** actually reads the `/boot` Directory as Empty.

Is there a way to fix this?

Edit: I forgot, previously, to say my Computer is `BIOS`, not `UEFI`.

Comment: There is no boot mounted. the partition table is:
/dev/sdb1 -- BIOS Filesystem
/dev/sdb2 -- Linux Filesyste,

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: Ok i edited my recent question, Sorry I am new

Comment: Could you provide a link to the exact procedure you're using to install Arch? And the exact commands you use to install GRUB? When you see the error message, you'll probably see a `grub rescue>` prompt; if you type in `set` and press Enter, what values does it display for `root` and `prefix`?

Comment: I am deciding not to edit my question atm but i'll just comment set 
cmdpath=(hd0)
prefix=(hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub
root=hd0,gpt
I used a variety of sources to install this (The wiki was the first, and a few bits of a tutorial that used UEFI)

Comment: If `root` is indeed `hd0,gpt`, then try typing into the `grub rescue>` prompt: `set root=hd0,gpt2`, Enter, `ls`, Enter. Does it see the contents of your Linux partition now? (I've got to go to sleep; but I'll continue this tomorrow if nobody else will.)

Comment: root is hd0,gpt2 small note.

Comment: I feel like that it might be somehow my installation-process. I'll retry the installation and record it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i've tried so many times and it seems like i cant install it. I Think I'm about to give up